# Can you create the indicator functions for closed and open intervals from indicator functions for half-open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a set $S$, the set of all (finite) linear combinations of indicator functions on bounded half-open intervals $(a,b]$, then does this set include all indicator functions on bounded intervals (and linear combinations thereof)?

---

If I had the linear span of indicator functions on open intervals or closed intervals, this would obviously be true, since you can make the indicator function of an isolated point with open sets like this:

$$1_{\{a\}} = 1_{(b,c)} - 1_{(b,a)} - 1_{(a,c)}$$

for some $b<a<c$, then you can just add and subtract the end points of any interval to get closed and half-open indicator functions. For closed sets, it's trivial.

But can you do something similar with half-open intervals? I don't think you can, but how would I prove it?

Comment: Can yo use the constant function $\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,\infty)}(x)\equiv1$?

Comment: No, I am required to only use bounded intervals. I don't know how that would help though, seeing as $(-\infty,\infty)$ isn't a half open interval anyway.